# unattended install (passive) for MySQL CE on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows-installer

I'm attempting to perform a silent install via a shell command from a migration wizard I am building.

```
msiexec /i E:\mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi /passive
```

While this does initiate the installer, and demands several user interactions due to `UAC`, it still goes through a normal install.

Is there a way to do a passive install of `MySQL CE` with "typical" settings from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would work if `mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi` were a real installer but Oracle made it a "trojan installer." All it does is install other installers and then launch another app that installs them. It appears Oracle made some effort to handle the case of a silent install but requires you to pass in command-line arguments.

After you run the trojan installer, there are GUI and command-line installers in the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Installer` directory. They install the .msi packages from the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer\Product Cache` directory. There's documentation for the [GUI and command-line installers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-installer.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will look over the documentation (much appreciated for that) and attempt a silent install.

Comment: Thanks again. I had to abandon MySQL CE due to some nice vendor lock-in by Microsoft :) Now I am forced to use SQL Server Express. ODBC and older MS platforms are horrible with 32/64-bit compatibility. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the no-install zip of MySQL to your desktop.
2. Open the Zip File in (Window1). You should see the data folder, bin
   folder, several `my.ini` files and other files.
3. Create a Server Folder and a Data Folder in a Desired Location.

```
    md C:\MySQLSrv
    md C:\MySQLData
```

1. Open `C:\MySQLSrv` in Window Explorer (Window2)
2. Copy and Paste the Zip Contents  into the `C:\MySQLSrv` (Window2)
3. Open `C:\MySQLSrv\data` in Windows Explorer (Window3)
4. Open `C:\MySQLData` in Window Explorer (Window4)
5. Copy and Paste the Contents of `C:\MySQLSrv\data` (Window3) into
   `C:\MySQLData` (Window4)
6. Close Window3 and Window4
7. Open a DOS Window and run the following DOS commands

```
    cd C:\MySQLSrv
    copy my-medium.ini my.ini
    notepad my.ini
    define datadir="C:\\MySQLData"
    cd C:\MySQLSrv\bin
    mysqld --install MySQLNew
    net start MySQLNew
```

11 . Close all Windows

You should be done !!!